# Can't setup "components" in coverity dashboard

Tags: components, coverity

Currently, I cannot change or add components in the coverity dashboard.

- Dashboard displays no components ("-no components configured-")
- Adding a component causes the error "Failed to update components. Please check regular expression and make sure to provide unique name for each component"

To me it looks like the dashboard has a hiccup of sorts.
All my project's defects are in the component "Other" (Pattern ".*") -- which does not turn up in the dashboard :(

Comment: Components are genuinely awful.  I strongly recommend you do not use them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We're investigating this issue right now as it seems to be affecting multiple projects. I'll post back when we've found the root cause and the fix.

Comment: I looks like one of our servers was in an inconsistent state preventing the update of component maps. It's been restarted; please try again.